# Auto Hot key for toggling stealth in Middle Earth Shadow of Mordor

Tags: autohotkey

Currently there is no toggle stealth in middle earth shadow of Mordor. So I tried to use auto hot key for toggling. My little finger hurts a lot when i keep holding. So I found this auto hot key script from here. https://steamcommunity.com/app/241930/discussions/0/617319460876561937/?l=italian#c490125103631105925

But this code does not seem to be working. I have autohotkey installed and also verified that it runs the sample msg box saying escape on pressing escape key program. I also remapped stealth to LCtrl. This is the 1st time I am using autohotkey. I have placed this file (shadow_of_mordor_stealth.ahk) in the same folder as the game's exe file is in. Thanks.

Update : As pointed by Sir Teddy The First, running in admin mode now works. Thankyou all for your help.

Comment: Do you have AutoHotKey installed on your machine? And did you actually run this script or did you just put it in the game's folder? If the script is running you'll see the AutoHotKey-icon in the tray.

Comment: Yes. I have auto hot key and also ran a sample program where pressing esc will pop up a msg box saying escape. I ran this script before giong to game.

Comment: Could you try using just `#IfWinActive ahk_exe ShadowOfMordor.exe` and see if that changes anything?

Comment: Nope. It does not seem to work.

Comment: Could you use the *TaskManager* to verify that the process is actually called `ShadowOfMordor.exe`?  
Also, you should not have to put the *AutoHotkey*-script inside the installation folder. Try launching it from somewhere else.

Comment: You should also try to run the script with *Admin*-privileges.

Comment: Many games have put in protection against cheating with things like AutoHotKey. So it might be that AutoHotKey is blocked from sending to your game.

Comment: Could be, but judging from the Steam-thread, the script works for others without problems.

Comment: Hi Teddy, Thanks. Running it in admin now works. Thanks for your help.